# May I create a database using assigned variable in PyMySQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, pymysql

I am learning PyMySQL. If I asked anything silly, please forgive me.

I hope to create a script which can automatically tell whether the database is existing or not. If not, will create the one. If exist, will do nothing. Below is my scripts. I could not create the database. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector as sql
from mysql.connector import Error
import os

#create a database
db_name = input("Input database name:")
db_name = db_name.strip()

try:
    db = sql.connect(host='localhost',
                     user='user',
                     password='SQLpractice',
                    )
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # cursor.execute("flg = False if NOT EXISTS Electronics;")
    if os.path.isfile(db_name):
        flg = True
        print(db_name, " exists. Nothing to do.\n")
    else:
        flg = False
        print(db_name," does not exist. Will create it if no errors happened.\n")    
        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s",(db_name) )

    print("Show database below.\n")
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
except Error as e:
    print("Error, cannot create database, database exists or something else wrong.\n")
finally:
    if flg:
        print("Created database.\n")
    else:
        print("No database created. Database exists or something wrong (flg=",flg,").\n")
```

Comment: What is the error returned by the server?

Comment: No error message, but there is not database created.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `if os.path.isfile(db_name):` line. It checks for a file existence and if it is there then it will not create database. I would suggest trying to create a database without any condition inside a try block. If database exists then it will throw an exception which you can catch otherwise it will simply create the database.

Comment: but if the database doesn't exist, the scripts can create a database.